# How to pass c# list to javascript function in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8

i am using the following code to send c# list to java script function

**c#**

```
private void browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{        
    List<string> arguments = new List<string>();
    arguments.Add("foo");
    arguments.Add("bar");

    // or simpler to use string join.

    browser.InvokeScript("getMemoryUsageCallback", arguments.ToArray());
}
```

**my javascript file**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function onLoad() {
         window.external.notify("getMemoryUsage");
     }

</script>
<script>

    $(function getMemoryUsageCallback() {

        var stringArgs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
            stringArgs.push(arguments[i]);


        $("#accordion").append(" <h3>" + stringArgs.pop(1) + "</h3><div><p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac liberoac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p> <ul><li>List item one</li> <li>List item two</li><li>List item three</li> </ul></div> ")
            $("#accordion").accordion();

    })
</script>
```

But I am not able to get the value of the list in java script file. When I tried to access the value of list in java script file by using the following code i am getting

```
function(selector, context) {// The JQuery object is actually just the init constructor enhanced  return new jquery.fn.init(selector,context,rootjQuery) }
```

Is there a way to access c# list in javascript file for windows phone.

Comment: Use JSON. both C# & Javascript work best with Json :)

Comment: how to use json can you elaborate

Comment: Tried http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Comment: can you please explain it with one example

Comment: @madanV there is example in the linked page, what more you want?

Comment: how can i pass the json string to javascript  $(function getMemoryUsageCallback(){ } function and how can i access that jsoon string to create a dynamic accordion menu i am not able to understand that example. please modify my code to use that example.